# Dynamic storages in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, dynamic, persistent-volumes

I have an application running on Kubernetes that needs to access SMB shares that are configured dynamically (host, credentials, etc) within said application. I am struggling to achieve this (cleanly) with Kubernetes.

I am facing several difficulties:

- I do not want "a" storage, I want explicitly specified SMB shares
- These shares are dynamically defined within the application and not known beforehand
- I have a variable amount of shares and a single pod needs to be able to access all of them

We currently have a solution where, on each kubernetes worker node, all shares are mounted to mountpoints in a common folder. This folder is then given as `HostPath` volume to the containers that need access to those storages. Finally, each of those containers has a logic to access the subfolder(s) matching the storage(s) he needs.

The downside, and the reason why I'm looking for a cleaner alternative, is:

- `HostPath` volumes present security risks
- For this solution, I need something outside Kubernetes that mounts the SMB shares automatically on each Kubernetes node

Is there a better solution that I am missing?

The Kubernetes object that seems to match this approach the most closely is the Projected Volume, since it "maps existing volume sources into the same directory". However, it doesn't support the type of volume source I need and I don't think it is possible to add/remove volume sources dynamically without restarting the pods that use this Projected Volume.

Comment: So SMB shares are not the same for all pods? You said that SMB shares are configured dynamically - is it (SMB share) changing on one pod? Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: The SMB shares are the same for all pods. The shares are configurable. When a share is added, all pods must be able to access that new share (when needed), in addition to the other ones. We use Kubernetes 1.21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure your current solution using HostPath on the nodes is not flexible, not secure thus it is not a good practice.

I think you should consider using one of the custom drivers for your SMB shares:

- [CIFS FlexVolume Plugin](https://github.com/fstab/cifs#cifs-flexvolume-plugin-for-kubernetes) - older solution, not maintained
- [SMB CSI Driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-smb#smb-csi-driver-for-kubernetes) - actively developed (recommended)

---

**CIFS FlexVolume Plugin**:

This solution is older and it is replaced by a CSI Driver. The advantage compared to CSI is that you can specify [SMB shares directly from the pod definition (including credentials as Kubernetes secret) as you prefer](https://github.com/fstab/cifs#running).

[Here](https://github.com/fstab/cifs#installing) you can find instructions on how to install this plugin on your cluster.

**SMB CSI Driver**:

This driver will automatically take care of [mounting SMB shares on all nodes by using DaemonSet](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-smb/blob/master/deploy/v1.4.0/csi-smb-node.yaml).

You can install SMB CSI Driver either by [bash script](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-smb/blob/master/docs/install-csi-driver-master.md#install-smb-csi-driver-master-version-on-a-kubernetes-cluster) or by using [a helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-smb/tree/master/charts).

Assuming you have your SMB server ready, you can use one of the following solution to access it from your pod:

- [Storage class](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-smb/blob/master/deploy/example/e2e_usage.md#option1-storage-class-usage)
- [PV/PVC](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-smb/blob/master/deploy/example/e2e_usage.md#option2-pvpvc-usage)

In both cases you have to use a previously created secret with the credentials.

In your case, for every SMB share you should create a Storage class / PV and mount it to the pod.

The advantage of CSI Driver is that it is [newer, currently maintained solution and it replaced FlexVolume](https://medium.com/flant-com/kubernetes-volume-plugins-from-flexvolume-to-csi-c9a011d2670d).

Below is diagram representing how CSI plugin operates:
[image]

Also check:

- [Kubernetes volume plugins evolution from FlexVolume to CSI](https://medium.com/flant-com/kubernetes-volume-plugins-from-flexvolume-to-csi-c9a011d2670d)
- [Introducing Container Storage Interface (CSI) Alpha for Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/01/introducing-container-storage-interface/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the in-depth explanation.
If I understand correctly the diagram, the CSI plugin still relies on Hostpath volumes behind the scenes though. There is also no magic here: "privileged: true" is required and is the reason (also a security issue) why we ended up mounting the shares natively on the nodes instead.
Unless I missed something, this also doesn't solve my need to access a variable amount of storages from the same container. In retrospect, this is probably the wrong way to address this requirement. A better approach would be to have dedicated pods for each storage.